# IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseIdentity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm following an example to configure ASP.NET Core Identity on **ASP.NET Core 3.0**

Here's the code for StartUp.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Users_WEB_APP.Models;

namespace Users_WEB_APP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ASPNET_IDENTITY:ConnectionString"]));
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

But at line
**app.UseIdentity();**
I'm getting the error

> 'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseIdentity',
> and no accessible extension method 'UseIdentity' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you messing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**What is it that I'm doing Wrong?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Documentation says that as of ASP.NET Core 2.2, [`UseIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.builderextensions.useidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is now obsolete and that [`UseAuthentication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.authappbuilderextensions.useauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_AuthAppBuilderExtensions_UseAuthentication_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_) should be used instead

> This method is obsolete and will be removed in a future version. The recommended alternative is `UseAuthentication(IApplicationBuilder)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.builderextensions.useidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

It works for me

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) questions and answers that you found helpful.